# Keyword 'of' in Java

Tags: java, syntax

I was reading the source code for a GitHub project (JClouds-Chef) and stumbled across the [most peculiar looking Java](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/chef-basics/src/main/java/org/apache/jclouds/examples/chef/basics/MainApp.java#L292):

```
Iterable<Module> modules =
    ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SshjSshClientModule(), new SLF4JLoggingModule(),
        new EnterpriseConfigurationModule());
```

What is `of`? How is this valid Java? Is `of` a method? If so, where is it defined? Is it some weird, obscure Java operator that is hardly ever used? Is it something weird like a lambda? I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out where it is, what it does, and where it's defined!

Comment: No there is no "of" keyword in java. Hmm

Comment: https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#of%28%29

Comment: Please avoid multiple question and exclamation signs especially when asking trivial questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a method of [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#of()) (from Google Collections) of course. Is the static generic `<Module>` throwing you off there? It should work without it as well, since it can be inferred from the beginning part, so it could be written as just `ImmutableSet.of(...)`.

Comment: I think it's the space that threw me. I would not normally write `ImmutableSet. of(` so I would not expect `ImmutableSet.<Module> of(`

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman (+1) - it was the space for me as well. Had it been `ImmutableSet.<Module>of(...)` I would have stared at it for 5 - 10 seconds and then made sense of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#of()). It is a generic, static method. [This Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) can tell you more about those.

Generic static methods allow you to specify that parameter or return types of static methods should be inferred or specified upon calling the method.

An example from the tutorial is the following:

```
public class Util {
    // Generic static method
    public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
               p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the [Google Collections library](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html). He is using the method to get immutable ordered sets.